# Getting data out of an XML column using SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a temp table that contains account IDs and customer IDs and an xml field

```
#tempXML(uniqueidentifier AccountId, uniqueidentifier CustomerId, xml xmlData)
```

The XML field is similar to this where the FieldId is a uniqueidentifier that tells me what data is being stored in the FieldValue field. I was able to get some of the data out using the following SQL. I had to write it multiple times increasing the value int he brackets by 1 each time to look in every field, but this causes problems if a FieldValue is not set for prop FieldIds.

```
SELECT  #tempXML.customFieldData.value('(CustomFields/Field/FieldValue)[7]', 
    'varchar(10)') AS dataField
FROM #tempXML 
WHERE #tempXML.customFieldData.value('(CustomFields/Field/FieldId)[7]', 
    'varchar(36)') = '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222'
```

This is a sample of one of the XMl fields. The data can be in any order, and not all FieldIds are used or have FieldValues associated with them.

```
<CustomFields>
  <Field>
    <FieldId>aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa</FieldId>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <FieldId>bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbb9c</FieldId>
    <FieldValue />
 </Field>
 <Field>
    <FieldId>cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc</FieldId>
    <FieldValue />
 </Field>
 <Field>
    <FieldId>dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd</FieldId>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>eeeeeeee-eeee-eeee-eeee-eeeeeeeeeeee</FieldId>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</FieldId>
   <FieldValue>more data</FieldValue>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</FieldId>
   <FieldValue>What I want</FieldValue>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</FieldId>
   <FieldValue>Some Data</FieldValue>
 </Field>
</CustomFields>
```

The problem I am having is I can only look at the nth Field in the XMl record with my current code, and if that FieldId exists, but does not have a FieldValue, it grabs the next present FieldValue.

All the examples I have been able to find use unique names for FieldId which allows them to jump to them easily and know what time of data to expect in those fields. I cannot do those with the given XML data.

Does anyone know how I might go about tackling this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `SELECT A.B.value('FieldValue[1]', 'varchar(255)') FROM #tempXML AS T CROSS APPLY T.customFieldData.nodes('CustomFields/Field') AS A(B) CROSS APPLY A.B.nodes('FieldId[text()="22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"]') AS C(D);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
(N'<CustomFields>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</FieldId>
   <FieldValue>more data</FieldValue>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</FieldId>
   <FieldValue>What I want</FieldValue>
 </Field>
 <Field>
   <FieldId>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</FieldId>
   <FieldValue>Some Data</FieldValue>
 </Field>
</CustomFields>');
```

--This is the field's ID you are searching for

```
DECLARE @SearchFor UNIQUEIDENTIFIER='22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222';
```

--And this is the actual query

```
SELECT t.YourXML.value(N'(/CustomFields/Field[FieldId=sql:variable("@SearchFor")]/FieldValue)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
FROM @mockupTable AS t;
```

You can pass in a variables value using `sql:variable()` and you can use an `XQuery predicate` to set a filter within your `XQuery`.